# How to enable Firebase as a custom authentication provider for my Azure Active Directory app?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm developing an app with Ionic and Azure Active Directory, and I would like to add Firebase as my front end and backend authentication provider.

Azure currently supports Microsoft, Facebook , Google, and Twitter, they also say that you can add your own provider but I just don't have any idea of how to do it, I don't have too much experience with this.

A step by step guide could help a lot on this.

Comment: Can you reference the article that says that Microsoft, Facebook, Google and Twitter are supported? Just want to be sure I know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

To add the custom authentication for mobile back-end, we need to implement an `ApiController` to handle the login request. Here is an example that which velidate the user from the database(full code sample refer this site):

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Http;
using Backend.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Backend.Controllers
{
    [Route(".auth/login/custom")]
    public class CustomAuthController : ApiController
    {
        private MobileServiceContext db;
        private string signingKey, audience, issuer;

        public CustomAuthController()
        {
            db = new MobileServiceContext();
            signingKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");
            var website = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME");
            audience = $"https://{website}/";
            issuer = $"https://{website}/";
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] User body)
        {
            if (body == null || body.Username == null || body.Password == null ||
                body.Username.Length == 0 || body.Password.Length == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest(); ;
            }

            if (!IsValidUser(body))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            var claims = new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, body.Username)
            };

            JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(
                claims, signingKey, audience, issuer, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
            return Ok(new LoginResult()
            {
                AuthenticationToken = token.RawData,
                User = new LoginResultUser { UserId = body.Username }
            });
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool IsValidUser(User user)
        {
            return db.Users.Count(u => u.Username.Equals(user.Username) && u.Password.Equals(user.Password)) > 0;
        }
    }

    public class LoginResult
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "authenticationToken")]
        public string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
        public LoginResultUser User { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginResultUser
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userId")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below link is also helpful about custom authentication for the mobile apps:

[Work with the .NET backend server SDK for Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth)

Comment: Hello @fei-xue-msft , thanks for your answer, i have a question: Where does **AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken** comes from, can i use that in an ionic app, if no, what alternatives do i have to generate a "AAD" token from client side?

Comment: The `AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken` method comes from [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login/). When we protect the mobile app, actually we protect the mobile back-end, we are not able to use it in the client-side like ionic app. The token is always issue from 'server' and it used by client to request the resource. If I misunderstood please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I've made some research on this, won't be able to use your code, but there's a NodeJS library called azure-mobile-apps, which I think I can use to generate a token am i right? Have you done that before?

Comment: @MoisesEliasValera Did you get any error message? The code above is developing with C# and it works well for me.  If you were developing the back-end using node.js, the most of code should be same. You just to replace the code to get the key and sign-in the token.